# How to subtract from numbers following a string in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am trying to subtract from numbers following a string in VIM, for example this (searched) input:

`CustomModelData: 1`

And my preferred (replaced) output:

`CustomModelData: -2147483647`

The number that I am trying to subtract from the numbers is 2147483648. I tried using this in VIM, but it doesn't work since there is a string in the expression, I want to keep the string while also subtracting from the number that follows:

`:%s/CustomModelData: \d\+/\=/CustomModelData: submatch(0)-2147483648/g`

Comment: Do you have to use vim for this problem? Tools such as awk can do a much better job:
`awk -F ': ' 'BEGIN { OFS=": "} {print $1, $2 - 2147483648}' data-file`

Comment: No, I never considered using awk, I will try it out.

Comment: I tried entering the command and I got this error:
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { OFS=:
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
errcount: 1

Comment: Can you try `awk -F ': ' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {print $1, $2 - 2147483648}' data-file`

Comment: It seems to work, but it doesn't seem to go throughout the file (it only does the first one), and also, I had to add the "CustomModelData" before the first colon to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following minor adjustment to have the match start at the number so the replacement only sees the number to adjust

```
%s/\vCustomModelData: \zs\d+/\=submatch(0)-2147483648/g
```

- \zs  [anything, sets start of match](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

If each number is on a separate line of the file, then you can match relevant lines and use the `Ctrl`+`X` subtraction operator on them:

```
:g/CustomModelData:/ norm 2147483648^X
```

(For the `^X`, type `Ctrl`+`X`.)